# sed regex fails to capture the entire paragraph containing the pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, xml

I have this XML file (example)

```
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/>


<This is a line of text with a year=33020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=33020 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=33020 the month=2/>
```

Using the `sed` installation provided by my Linux distribution ( sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2) I search within this file with the following regexp:

```
 sed -En 'N;s/\<(This.*2020.*[\s\S\n]*?)\>/\1/gp' test2.txt
```

However, it captures only this string:

```
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
```

But I try to capture the entire first *paragraph* between `<` and `>` that contains the pattern.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sed really isn't the best tool for something like this. Are you open to solutions using other tools?

Comment: yeah sure but they need to be linux native

Comment: Is all text in your file organized in these XML-tag-like structures? Is it in reality an XML file? Alternatively, are the paragraphs you are interested always separated by a blank newline?

Comment: @user63898, what does "linux native" mean for you? Stuff usually available in a default installation of a usual Linux desktop/server distribution? Which probably pretty much means the GNU equivalents of the standard POSIX tools, except that e.g. Debian installs Perl by default too...

Comment: Are you in fact parsing XML?  There are tools for doing that conveniently, efficiently, and safely.

Comment: yes im parsing xml

Comment: `[\s\S\n]*?` also smell like Perl-isms. In particular, `x*?` is undefined in standard extended REs; IIRC the GNU implementation treats it as an optional `x*`, which is the same as just `x*`. GNU tools support _some_ of the `\x` classes, but I never remember _which_ ones, and I'm not sure if they work inside `[]` either.

Comment: Please post well-formed XML that we may test answers on.  The document fragments that you show are _not_ real XML.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong here?` You're not using an XML parser. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/864696

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work as you expect is that `<` and `>` do not need to be escaped in regular expressions, they don't have any special meaning. However, `\<` and `\>` *do* have special meaning for GNU extended regular expressions (which you activate with `-E`): they match at word boundaries. `\<` matches the beginning of a word and `\>` the end. So `\<(This` isn't actually matching the `<`, it is matching the beginning of the word `This`. Similarly for the `\>` at the end. The GNU `sed` manual has [an example](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiline-techniques.html#Multiline-techniques) which is almost exactly what you're after:

```
$ sed -En '/./{H;1h;$!d} ; x; s/(<This.*2020.*?>)/\1/p;' file
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/>
```

---

I find `sed` particularly ill-suited to this sort of task. I would use `perl` instead:

```
$ perl -000 -ne 'chomp;/<.*2020.*?>/s && print "$_\n"; exit' file
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/>
```

Here, we are using Perl in "paragraph mode" (`-000`) which means that a "line" is defined by two consecutive `\n` characters, by a blank line. The script will:

- `chomp`: remove the trailing newline at the end of the "line" (paragraph).
- `/<.*2020.*?>/s && print "$_\n"`: if this "line" (paragraph) matches a `<` then 0 or more characters until `2020` and zero or more characters and then a `>`, then print this line appending a newline character (`print "$_\n"`). The `s` modifier to the match operator allows `.` to match newlines.

---

Another option is `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"} /<.*2020.+?>/' file
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/>
```

We set the record separator `RS` to two consecutive newlines and then match using the same regex as above. Since in `awk` the default behavior when a match is found (or any other operation returns true) is to print the current record, this will print out what you need.

Comment: Note that this will pick up nodes that happen to have _other attributes_ that have the value `2020` (or where `2020` is a substring of some value or attribute name). You most likely also want to include the node's tag name in the expression (`This` in the example).

Comment: When collecting all lines in hold space, you can do `H;1h`, so for the first line you overwrite the appended line with just the line.

Comment: i have still problem if i add "-i" flag and run :
sed -i -En '/./{H;$!d} ; x; s/(<This.*2020.*?>)/\1/p;' file 
it will erase all the content of the file and leave only the paragraph that it is working on

Comment: still have another problem see new question here : 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662974/sed-command-succesfuly-find-and-replace-in-file-bit-erasing-everything-in-the

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, but that isn't part of the question. I don't want to guess what the OP really wants to do, all I have to go on is what's in the question.

Comment: @user63898 well yes, of course it will. Why would you use this with `-i`? Your question is showing an example file with two "paragraphs" and you say you only want the first one. Remember that we cannot magically guess what you want: you need to tell us.

Comment: @Philippos thanks, answer edited.

Comment: Hmm... The document in the question is not XML, so it's clearly not the data they are working with. If that's not their data, then it may potentially contain the substring `2020` in other parts of the node than what they are showing.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know. But this is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 6):

First, most text-processing tools such as `sed` or `awk` work on a line-by-line basis, so matching entire paragraphs takes a little bit of extra effort. It is possible, but it is also one of the reasons for the unexpected output you are seeing.

Second, your input looks like structured text due to the XML-tag delimiting characters. As such, it might be best processed using `xmlstarlet` or another dedicated tool. (**Update**: Since you confirmed this in a comment now, I would strongly recommend using `xmlstarlet` or a similar tool.)

That said, if your text looks like in your example, and you have an `awk` installation that accepts multi-character record separators (like GNU Awk), the following program should work:

```bash
awk -v RS="<|/>" '/2020/' input.txt
```

The `RS` variable, if consisting of more than one character, will be interpreted as regular expression, so either a `<` or a `/>` will be treated as "record separator", instead of the default `\n`. Therefore, any matching conditions will apply to the entire text between these tags, and not just individual lines.

Result:

```
This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2
```

Note that the "tag-open" `<` and "tag-close" `/>` character combinations are stripped from the output because they are chosen as record separator. On the other hand, this means it will also work if the "paragraphs" are not separated by blank lines. (*However, if there is "stray" text matching your pattern outside of such tags, it would also be matched.*)

You would place the regular expression you are looking for inside the `/ ... /` part of the program (just as in a `sed` adress statement). If you are looking for a fixed string, however, I would recommend

```bash
awk -v RS="<|/>" 'index($0,"2020")' input.txt
```

instead.

Comment: the awk is working but i need the sed feature that can search and replace in file using regexp groups 
that is the text that captured will be replaces with comment xml tags ( <!-- \1 --> )

Comment: I see. If that is the case, please state this in your question from the beginning. In your case, since your actual question starts to deviate substantially from the posted one, please open a new question including all relevant conditions (i.e. actual, if possibly anonymized, XML content along with desired results). You may still want to accept one of the answers here that most closely did what you were asking for in the question originally.

Comment: You may want to test this with an XML file having an attribute called `os2020` and/or an attribute value that is `2020-01-01` or `vision 2020` or whatever, you get what I mean. And you don't even look at the node's tag name.

Comment: @Kusalananda of course. Had I known that this was about true XML parsing, I would not have suggested that. But the answer does what the OP originally asked about, so I hink I will let it stand for the time being. The caveats I placed on top should alert any future reader about the shortcomings ...+

Comment: @user63898 `awk` can do regex search and replace like `sed` using the `sub()`, `gsub()`, and (on GNU awk) `gensub()` functions.   with capture groups.    Processing XML, though, should be done with an xml parser (like `xmlstarlet` or `xq`, or with an xml parsing library for perl or python or whatever), not with regular expressions.   Also worth looking at it `xml2`, which converts XML to a line-oriented format suitable for use with line-oriented tools like sed.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a well-formed XML document like this:

```xml
<root>
<thing  year="2019"
        month="1"
        day="1" />
<thing  year="2020"
        month="5"
        day="13" />
<thing  year="2021"
        month="7"
        day="3" />
</root>
```

You may extract a copy of each `thing` node that has the value `2020` in their `year` attribute using `xmlstarlet` like this:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//thing[@year = "2020"]' -nl file
<thing year="2020" month="5" day="13"/>
```

Note that whitespace within a node, between its attributes, is irrelevant to the contents of the document.

Comment: xmlstarlet is not installed by default on the servers

Comment: @user63898 Then you may want to install it, especially since you're dealing with XML documents.

Comment: this is not option for me , thanks fo rthe help

Comment: @user63898 May I ask whether your issue relates to a private or professional project?

Comment: @user63898 yes, of course, if you don't have a hacksaw then it's perfectly fine to use a hammer as a substitute. they're both tools, after all, and you already have the hammer.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

Here are two answers, inspired by other answers in this thread. The first answer splits on paragraphs (inspired by @terdon and @AdminBee), then `grep`s for the correct year:

```
raku -e 'slurp.split("\n\n").grep(/2020/).put;'
```

Result:

```
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/>
```

According to one Larry Wall, Raku provides functions that make it really easy to do more from inside the language, lessening the reliance on specialized command-line switches. See "Trick #2" at:

https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2020/07/msg9004.html

The second approach is using Raku's `comb` routine, which takes a regex "matcher" and breaks text into elements outside the match (useful for further processing). As the Raku Docs describe it, `comb`: *"Searches for `$matcher` in `$input` and returns a `Seq` of non-overlapping matches limited to at most `$limit` matches."*

```
raku -e '.put for slurp.comb(/^^ "<This" .*? "/>" $$ / ).grep(/2020/);'
```

Result:

```
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/>
```

The code above breaks before a `^^` *start-of-line* assertion and after a `$$` *end-of-line* assertion. By default, the `.` dot wildcard matches whitespace in Raku (including newlines), so `comb` above can break the text into multi-line chunks (elements).

Far-and-away, the most satisfying results on authentic XML documents will be using a dedicated `XML` tool and/or library, such as Raku with the community-supported `XML` module:

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML
https://raku.org/

Comment: the problem i have only perl 5 installed , can't install new perl

Comment: @user63898 understandable. Maybe my answer will be helpful for others then.